# How to add shape keys to dimension of an object

Tags: modeling, shape-keys

I am scaling one mesh plane using key frame but i am not able to see any effect in values of scaling of an object but yaa dimension of an object is changing.
So, i want to know that how to add shapekeys to affect the dimension of an object or how to scale object using shape key without affecting dimension of an object

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions is just consequence of outside vertices rotated and scaled in object space. It could be modified only manually or by a script.

Comment: So, if i want to scale a mesh plane with the help of shape keys, how i will do it? , because after scaling i am getting the change in values in dimension panel not in scale panel. Due to which i am not able to add shape keys in timeline

Comment: You can scale, rotate or move vertices in edit mode and store in shape keys - those actions only affect it location inside mesh data.
Object location, rotation and scale transform mesh data depending on it origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, it really helps me a lot.

Comment: One more thing i have to ask is that how can we use shape key data to add keyframe using set keyframe nodes?....I will be very thankful if you will let me know

Comment: as most of other values, just use "insert keyframe" on it: create basis, add key and set it value to one, edit mesh data with it, now change keyframe and insert keyframe of shapekey - you can use fraction of one.